# MySQL phpMyAdmin not showing in web browser in Ubuntu LAMP server

Tags: apache2, lamp, phpmyadmin

LAMP is not installing in Ubuntu 16.04. When I typed `localhost/phpmyadmin` in Firefox it showed this message:

```
404 Not Found
The requested URL /phpmyadmin was not found on this server.  
Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80
```

Comment: How have you installed LAMP?

Answer (score 1):

LAMP means "Linux Apache MySQL PHP" and PhpMyAdmin is not a part of it.

The command for PhpMyAdmin installation is:

```
sudo apt install phpmyadmin
```

For more detailed steps, here you are [a good guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-phpmyadmin-on-ubuntu-16-04).